# Scipy integral comes out wrong

Tags: python, scipy, integral

I'm trying to integrate a function. The function is guaranteed to be non negative:

```
def function(x):
    something = ...
    something_else = ...
    return exp(something) / sqrt(something_else)
```

Now I'm integrating it:

```
def integrand(a, b):
    return scipy.integrate.quad(function, a, b)
```

The results I'm getting are not what I expect, so to check I did this:

```
for x in range(0, 10000):
    if integrand(0,x+1) < integrand(0,x):
        raise ValueError("Weird!")
```

Sure enough, I'm getting 'Weird' exceptions. How can that be?

Comment: Can you show an actual example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: It's kind of hard, because the actual example involves a 10,000-point C14 dating calibration curve...

Comment: Well, it's also kind of hard to debug the problem without a small test case.  Try to reduce the problem to a small test case.

Comment: Try doing a check of `function(0..10000)` for `< 0` to make 100% sure that it _never_ returns -ve numbers.

Comment: it hopefully shouldn't - from the very vague function definition one can still gather that `exp(something) / sqrt(something_else) > 0` if something positive is fed into `something_else`. But this type of guessing game is usually a waste of time - more info please!

Comment: I made sure that function is non-negative for range(0,10000,0.01). I'll try to find a small self-contained example for this. I thought this was a known issue with the way quad estimates the integral.

Answer (score 1):

Without a working example, it is difficult to debug your code, but here are some suggestions based on what you have shown.

[`quad`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) returns a tuple with two values: the estimate of the integral, and an estimate of the absolute error in the result.  You don't appear to be using just the first value in your code.  Try changing `integrand` to

```
def integrand(a, b):
    return scipy.integrate.quad(function, a, b)[0]
```

Note the `[0]` after the call to `quad`.

Next, you should print the values of `integrand(0, x)` and `integrand(0, x+1)` when you find a "weird" case.  If they are approximately the same, then normal numerical imprecision could destroy the order that you would theoretically expect.  Take a look at the second value returned by `quad`.  If that value is bigger than the difference between `integrand(0, x)` and `integrand(0, x+1)`, you can't really expect the estimates of the integrals to increase monotonically, because the expected increase is less than the error in the calculation.  If that is the problem, you could try setting `epsabs` and/or `epsrel` to values smaller than the default values of 1.49e-8, but that will only get you so far.  Eventually you run into the limits of floating point calculations.